# Implementing transition tables as threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I doing implementation of 
[FSSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firing_squad_synchronization_problem).

I want for each thread to represent a soldier, so my question is what most efficient and readable way to implement transition tables of soldiers in c?

I was thinking about 3 dimensional array, but maybe there is a better solution.
Here example of transition tables:

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: why a 3d array? you have a n soldiers to synchronize and a state machine...

Comment: 3d array is always a bad idea. Work around.